# method called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My purpose is to define ajax method callback with jquery. 
all DOM of parent div are loaded dynamically
i have define delete button foreach comments
and i want to get confirmation from twitter bootrap modal befor throw the ajax request : https://jsfiddle.net/r4sLt016/5/

```
     this.deleteComment = function () {
         self = this;
         $("button[name='deleteComment']").each(function (index, el) {
             $(this).unbind().bind('click', function (event) {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 var ref = $(this).attr('data-ref');
                 var callback = function () {
                     /*$.ajax({
                        url: '/path/to/file',
                        type: 'DELETE',
                        data: {param1: 'value1'},
                      })
                      .done(function() {
                        console.log("success");
                      })
                      .fail(function() {
                        console.log("error");

                      });*/
                     alert("multiple");
                 }
                 self.confirm("Delete Comment ", "Are you sure you want \
                   to delete this Comment ?", callback);
             });
         });
     }

     this.confirm = function(head, question, callback) {
            $(".modal-title").html(head);
            var body = $("<p/>").text(question);
            $(".modal-body").html(body);
            $("#deleteModal").click(function(event) {
                callback();
                $('.customModal').modal('hide');
            });
            $('.customModal').modal('show');
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use event delegation

Comment: @ArunPJohny you can vote for "duplicate of" instead of "off-topic"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding the click event `deleteModal` element everytime you call the `confirm()` method!
So you have to `unbind()` and `bind()` again like you did at the `deleteComment` buttons.

Like this:

```js
this.confirm = function(head, question, callback) {
        $(".modal-title").html(head);
        var body = $("<p/>").text(question);
        $(".modal-body").html(body);
        $("#deleteModal").unbind().bind('click', function(event) {
            callback();
            $('.customModal').modal('hide');
        });
        $('.customModal').modal('show');
}
```

[>> Updated JSfiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/r4sLt016/6/)